# Pythonで10進数ー＞2進数に変換するコードをライブラリを使わずにリスト内包表記で書きたい

Tags: python

下のコードをワンラインのリスト内包表記で書くことが出来るでしょうか。固定されたリストの要素を受け取るのではなくて、ループが進むごとに更新される値を受け取っての処理・・というものが実行できるのかが知りたいのです。

ずっとScheme系で遊んでたのでPythonにとってはすごく基本的なことかも知れないとは思うのですが調べても分かりませんでした。

```
def dec2bin(target):
    amari = []
    while target != 0:
        amari.append(target % 2)
        target = target // 2
    amari.reverse()
    return amari
```

Answer (score 2):

> ループが進むごとに更新される値を受け取って

リスト内包表記とは言えないけど

例えば `123`の場合

```py
r = [123, 0]; while r[-2]: r += divmod(r[-2], 2)

r[:1:-2]   # 結果
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
```

---

リスト内包表記だと,
ループ回数かイテラブル あるいはジェネレーターが必要になりそうなので

- ループ回数指定は, 他の回答にある通り
- イテラブルではムリと思われ
- ジェネレーターでは複数行になる

ので, それらを使わずに
(好ましくはないけれど)ループ内からリスト項目追加で処理する方法

```py
lst = [123]
[lst.append(r[0])or r[1]if(r:= divmod(n, 2))[0]else r[1]for n in lst][::-1]
```

---

**(更新)**

##### ① リスト内包表記で書くこと

[リストの内包表記 (List Comprehensions)](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) より

> 主な利用場面は、あるシーケンスや iterable (イテレート可能オブジェクト) のそれぞれの要素に対してある操作を行った結果を要素にしたリストを作ったり、ある条件を満たす要素だけからなる部分シーケンスを作成することです。

「元となる数値が次第に減っていき, 除数より小さくなれば終了」
というパターンは (for 〜 in sequence の処理には) 向かない

ジェネレータ関数 (generator function) を使えば, リスト内包表記の部分は一行で作れるけれど
これは普通に `while`文で(List Comprehensions使わず) 処理するほうが 無駄がない気がします

```py
def gen(n, d):
    while n:
        n, r = divmod(n, d)
        yield r

list(reversed([b for b in gen(123, 2)]))
```

#### ② 更新される値を受け取っての処理

Pythonでは代入は文であり, [式 (expression)](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/expressions.html#expressions)の中に 文 (statement)を含めることはできない

- [代入文 (assignment statement)](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/simple_stmts.html)

ただ, 文を式に置き換えることが可能な場合があり, 全て式に置き換えれば一行で処理を行えることもあります
(累算代入文 (augmented assignment statement) の置き換えの例)

```py
>>> lst = []
>>> lst += [10]
>>> lst.append(20)
>>> lst
[10, 20]
```

例えば, 以下のような リストの要素, アトリビュート, グローバル変数 の値の変更が可能

```py
>>> lst = [3]
>>> lst.__setitem__(0, lst[0] -1)
>>> lst
[2]
>>> var = type('var', (), dict(val=2))
>>> setattr(var, 'val', var.val -1)
>>> var.val
1
>>> cnt = 1
>>> globals().__setitem__('cnt', cnt +1)
>>> cnt
2
```

これらの呼び出しは `None`を返すことも多く, 変数に何らかの値を代入する際に以下のようにできます

```py
val = lst.__setitem__(0, lst[0] -1) or 何らかの値
```

Comment: oriri様、丁寧なご回答ありがとうございます！正直、今の段階では読み解くことが出来ないのですが、このような動作が可能であるという事が分かって楽しみです。今日からしばらく皆さんのコードの読み解きやります！あと、最小・軽量Linux楽しみにしております(^o^)

Answer (score 0):

> ライブラリを使わないで

[kunif氏の回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/98624/47127) から、`int.bit_length()` メソッドを利用する様に書き換えました。

<strike>`math.log2()` を使うので前提条件に反しますが、参考までに以下のコードを載せておきます。</strike>

```py
def dec2bin(target):
    amari = []
    while target != 0:
        amari.append(target % 2)
        target = target // 2
    return amari[::-1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = 13

    if x > 0:
        print(dec2bin(x))
        print([(x%2, (x := x//2))[0] for _ in range(x.bit_length())][::-1])
    elif x == 0:
        print([0])
    else:
        print('value should be greater than zero.')

# [1, 1, 0, 1]
# [1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: AIに質問しても頓珍漢な答えしか帰ってこなくて困り果ててました、みなさんから色々なパターンでご回答をいただけて大変ありがたかったです！早速読解作業にかかります！

Answer (score 0):

「ループが進むごとに更新される値を受け取っての処理」というのとは違うのですが、質問の処理の内容をリスト内包表記で1行でというのならおそらく以下でできるでしょう。
`0`やマイナス値については別途考慮の必要があるのは @metropolis さんの回答と同じですね。

```
target = 2863311530

binary_digit_list = [1 if (target & b) else 0 for b in [int(1 << m) for m in reversed(range(target.bit_length()))]]

print(binary_digit_list)
```

何か他の処理をする場合には、その処理の性質に基づいた別のコーディングが必要になりそうですね。

Comment: `[1<<m & target and 1 for m in range(target.bit_length())[::-1]]` で十分でしょう。

Comment: おおなるほど、個々の処理の区別が付くように段階をおって書いてみましたが、たしかにまとめて短縮できますね。

Comment: kunif様、metropolis様、ありがとうございます！実行してみたところ見事に変換出来ました！今の所まったく理解できない表記なので、これからじっくり読解させていただきます。このような動作が可能なのだと言うことが分かって助かりました！